# Combine two different strings in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two strings.

```
String_1 = "bb,bba,bbc";
Strings_2= "cc,cca,ccc";
```

I am not being able to create a mysql function where I will send those strings .
The function will receive two parameter and will return the combined json depending upon the string position.

And it will return

```
{
"bb":"cc",
"bba":"cca",
"bbc":"ccc"
}
```

I only want it in mysql

Comment: What have you tried so far and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I was irritating through and was trying to do it through the INSERT() command but no luck yet

Comment: Would the input always be CSV strings of length 3?

Comment: Even also tried with Replace but the problem is if replacing "bb" then all the "bb" is getting replaced

Comment: What is MySQL version precisely?

Comment: *I have two strings.* Where? in local variables? in table's column? else?

Comment: MySql Server 8.0

Comment: No have those two local variables ,not stored in table colomn

Comment: I.e. single literals?

Comment: @tim no that could be of any length but both the string size will remain same

Comment: This task would be much better handled outside of MySQL, in your application layer (e.g. Java, C#, PHP, Python, etc.).

Comment: Yes , two different strings I have got from two different MySQL store function , and hence need to perform the proposed operation

Comment: @Tim yes I got you but need to manage through sql only

Comment: MySQL is for the storage and retrieval of relational data, and not much else

Answer (score 1):

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION convert_to_JSON (string_1 TEXT, string_2 TEXT)
RETURNS JSON
RETURN (SELECT JSON_OBJECTAGG( t1.value, t2.value )
        FROM JSON_TABLE(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(string_1, ',', '","'), '"]'),
                        "$[*]" COLUMNS (ROWID FOR ORDINALITY,
                                        value VARCHAR(255) PATH '$')) t1
        JOIN  JSON_TABLE(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(string_2, ',', '","'), '"]'),
                        "$[*]" COLUMNS (ROWID FOR ORDINALITY,
                                        value VARCHAR(255) PATH '$')) t2 USING (ROWID));
```

and respectively

```
SELECT convert_to_JSON('bb,bba,bbc', 'cc,cca,ccc');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set @String_1 = "bb,bba,bbc";
set @Strings_2= "cc,cca,ccc";

with recursive cte(a) as (
    select 1 as a
    union all
    select a+1 from cte where a<3)
select json_objectagg(
            substring_index(substring_index(@string_1,',',cte.a),',',-1),
            substring_index(substring_index(@strings_2,',',cte.a),',',-1)) as json
from cte;
```

output:

```
+------------------------------------------+
| json                                     |
+------------------------------------------+
| {"bb": "cc", "bba": "cca", "bbc": "ccc"} |
+------------------------------------------+
```